# How to define optional parent route in angular

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I want users to navigate to same components if they go to the following url's

```
https://localhost:4200/Kotak/funds -- with parent route 'Kotak'
https://localhost:4200/Kotak/fund-houses -- with parent route 'Kotak'

https://localhost:4200/funds -- without parent route
https://localhost:4200/fund-houses -- without parent route
```

This is what I have started with for defining routes

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: ':fundHouseName',
        children: [{
            path: RoutePaths.funds,
            component: FundsComponent,
            canActivate: [AuthGuard]
        },
        {
            path: RoutePaths.fundHouses,
            component: FundHousesComponent,
            canActivate: [AuthGuard]
        }
        ]
    }
]
```

But when I define it like this, it always expects the `:fundHouseName` parameter in the url, so this works

```
https://localhost:4200/Kotak/funds
```

But this does not

```
https://localhost:4200/funds
```

As a solution what I could think of to have two parent routes define, one with parameter one without like this

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        children: getChildPaths()
    },
    {
        path: ':fundHouseName',
        children: getChildPaths()
    }
]
```

But I am thinking is there a better way of doing this without repeating the routes?

Something like marking `:fundHouseName` param as optional in some way?

Answer (score 0):

Just define a variable for children like so

You can use restructuring of child array to simplify the routing to below

```
const childRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: RoutePaths.funds,
        component: FundsComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthGuard]
    },
    {
        path: RoutePaths.fundHouses,
        component: FundHousesComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthGuard]
    }
    ];

const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: ':fundHouseName',
        children: childRoutes
    },
    ...childRoutes
]
```

Comment: It is almost same as the solution I was thinking. I do need to have parent route for both as I have common resolver. So basically there is no way to mark the parameter optional?

Comment: @PawanNogariya you need to specify it's own route there is no parameter optional

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can make the :fundHouseName parameter optional in your Angular route configuration by adding a question mark (?) after the parameter. This makes the parameter optional, and the route will match both with and without the :fundHouseName in the URL.

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: ':fundHouseName?',
        children: getChildPaths()
    }
];

function getChildPaths(): Route[] {
    return [
        {
            path: RoutePaths.funds,
            component: FundsComponent,
            canActivate: [AuthGuard]
        },
        {
            path: RoutePaths.fundHouses,
            component: FundHousesComponent,
            canActivate: [AuthGuard]
        }
    ];
}
```

Now, the following URLs will both navigate to the corresponding components:

- https://localhost:4200/Kotak/funds
- https://localhost:4200/funds

Similarly, for the fund houses:

- https://localhost:4200/Kotak/fund-houses
- https://localhost:4200/fund-houses